# Printing from column vector to row vector?

Tags: java

I am very new to Java. I have a 5*5 matrix in a file. When I am trying to import the elements of the matrix in a matrix variable and printing it, it prints in 25*1, not 5*5. How can I convert the individual column vector into the corresponding row vector?

It would be great if someone helps. Thanks

Comment: Showing some code will be helpful to help you...

Answer (score 1):

Store your data for the matrix in a [2D array](http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/cs231/lectures/chapter9/arrays2d.htm). If your matrix is 5x5 you'll need 5 an array of 5 arrays. If I were doing this, I'd write my own Matrix class to store and manipulate the matrix's contents, using 2d arrays internally.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like homework,

```
// Assuming you have a Vector holding Elements
Vector<Element> vector = new Vector<Element>();

// Populate vector

// Print vector contents in 5 X 5
int i = 0;
for (Element e : vector)  {
    // If already printed 5 elements
    if (i % 5 == 0) {
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
    System.out.print(e.toString() + ' ');
    i++;
}
```

This is if you're storing in a 1D collection. You can always use 2D array, or a self-containing List or Vector.

Answer (score 1):

You can have vector of vectors. But instead of `Vector` use [`ArrayList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html?is-external=true) (it's the same but without an unnecessary synchronization).

```
List<List<?>> 2dVector = new ArrayList<List<?>>()
```

Then you can call `2dVector.get(0).get(1)` for example. You will just have to initialize each item with `new ArrayList<?>`. Note that you can replace `?` with `String`, `Integer` or whatever your type is.